# Calling pipeline oracle function frm java class

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Basically what I want to do is call an oracle pipelined function from my java class.This oracle function has only one out parameter.

Comment: Can you provided more info plz?

Comment: i have an oracle pipelined function which returns a oracle collection. i need java code to call this pipeline function and get this oracle collection

Answer (score 1):

If you try to call a pipelined function in PL/SQL, i.e. outside SQL, you will get an error `PLS-00653: aggregate/table functions are not allowed in PL/SQL scope`.

If you try to call a function with an `OUT` parameter in SQL, you will get an error `ORA-06572: Function MYFUNC has out arguments`.

So, putting these two together, if you have a pipelined function with an `OUT` parameter, you can't call it in SQL nor outside SQL.  In other words, you can't call it at all.  Basically, it's a useless function.  Why Oracle lets you compile it at all is a mystery.

You will need to modify your function so that it is either (a) not pipelined, or (b) has no `OUT` parameter.

Comment: CallableStatement ftRPCaStmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN NAME_of_my_function ();END;");
 ftRPCaStmt.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.ARRAY,MY_ORACLE_COLLECTION); System.out.println(" collection >>>>>"+( ftRPCaStmt.getObject(1)));This is my code to call pipelined function.But I am getting below error."main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
ftRPCaStmt.execute();

Comment: @user2500313: I'm not at all surprised you got that error.  You tried to tell JDBC that the first placeholder (`?`) in your CallableStatement is an out parameter, but there aren't any placeholders in your CallableStatement.  Besides, have you rewritten your function as I suggested, or are you still intending to call your function as it is somehow, despite the fact that it can't actually be called?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I cann't see any particular need to get back table data from a package function, using a CallableStatement object.
Instead, we can use a normal sql query to wrap up the results and fetch them into a normal java resultset.
Doing so, we avoid trying to find a painful solution adjusting the package function (which uses package-level types), leaving the function and package types intact, as well as continue benefiting from using the unknowing internal functionality and speed of the pipelined plsql function.
Panos Zafiropoulos.